# String formatting potential string doubles or integer into integers

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

I receive a string from a server that sometimes is a double and sometimes is an integer. And i need it to be an integer. 
When i do a `Integer.parseInt(confusedStringNumber)`
If its a double, it throws a Number format exception. Is there a way to format the string to drop all decimal places whether they exist or not ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i = (int)Float.parseFloat("1.0");
int j = Float.valueOf("1.0").intValue();
```

Comment: Looks good, the only subtlety being whether it tunicates or rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following types and methods which can give you what you're asking for:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round-java.math.MathContext-